# Php / Laravel check for duplicate in loop

Tags: php, laravel, loops

I am trying to check whether a generated string is in my database table or not.

If there is no duplicate I want to return and save it.

If there is a duplicate I want to generate a new string and save it
currently this function does not return me the generated token:

```
public function checkForHashDuplicate($string)
{
    $newToken = '';
    $inquiries = DB::table('inquiries')->get();
    foreach($inquiries as $inquiryKey => $inquiryValue)
    {
        while($inquiryValue->android_device_token == $string)
        {
            $newToken = generateAlphanumericString();
            if($newToken != $inquiryValue->android_device_token)
            {
                return $newToken;
            }
        }
    }
}
$inquiry->android_device_token = $this->checkForHashDuplicate($hash);
```

Comment: you can use where condition in query.

Comment: Do **not** do this... the bigger the table the longer will it take to check, and you can end up in checking twice or trice or n times (forever); use UUID instead of this **crap** design!

Comment: @Kyslik yes the design is probably crap, but I do not have experience in this, could you explain how I built the UUID? Any online tutorial or your answer with information

Comment: @junikear search for uuid package and do research differences between v1,2,3,4,5 and see which fits best for your application; and instead of generating "token" generate UUID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simplified version of your code is:

```
public function checkForHashDuplicate($string)
{
    do {
        // generate token
        $newToken = generateAlphanumericString();
        // find token in a DB
        $duplicate = DB::table('inquiries')
            ->where('android_device_token', '=', $newToken)->first();

        // if token is FOUND `$duplicate` has truthy value
        // and `do-while` keeps running
        // else `$duplicate` is falsy and `do-while` breaks
    } while ($duplicate);

    return $newToken;
}
```

Comment: Ithink it's `while ($duplicate->isNotEmpty());` !!

Comment: If `->get();` is returning an empty `Collection`, would `while($duplicate);` equate to `true` in every loop regardless? I would either use `while(count($duplicate) == 0);` or switch the closure of that query to `->first();`, as that returns `null` if there's no matches. That being said, I could be wrong; I forget how empty collections are equated.

Comment: Now with `first` it's ok to use `while ($duplicate);` ;)

Comment: @TimLewis I suppose you're right, edited for `->first()`, which will definitely return something or not. `isNotEmpty()` is a solution too.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using:

```
$inquiries = DB::table('inquiries')->get();
```

and loop, use `where` like:

```
$inquiries = DB::table('inquiries')->where('android_device_token', '=', $string)->get();

if( count($inquiries ) == 1 )
{
  // found
}
else
{
  // Not found, generate new one
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check like this:

```
public function checkDuplicate($string){
    $count = DB::table('inquiries')->where('android_device_token',$string)->count();
    if($count==0){
         // $string exists
        return generateAlphanumericString();
    }else{
       // $string doesn't exists
       return $string;
    }
}
```

Now, use this function to assign value of `$string` or new token as

```
$inquiry->android_device_token = $this->checkForHashDuplicate($hash);
```

Hope you understand.